# Faster Startup of Processes Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to run two functions in Python3 in parallel. They both take about `30ms`, and unfortunately, after writing a testing script, I've found that the startup-time to get the processes running in the background takes over `100ms` which is a pretty high overhead that I would like to avoid. Is anybody aware of a faster way to run functions concurrently in Python3 (having a lower overhead -- ideally in the ones or tens of milliseconds) where I can still get the results of their functions in the main process. Any guidance on this would be appreciated, and if there is any information that I can provide, please let me know.

For hardware information, I'm running this on a 2019 MacBook Pro with Python 3.10.9 with a 2GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5.

I've provided the script that I've written below as well as the output that I typically get from it.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import numpy as np

def t(s):
    return (time.perf_counter() - s) * 1000

def run0(s):
    print(f"Time to reach run0: {t(s):.2f}ms")

    time.sleep(0.03)
    return np.ones((1,4))

def run1(s):
    print(f"Time to reach run1: {t(s):.2f}ms")

    time.sleep(0.03)
    return np.zeros((1,5))

def main():
    s = time.perf_counter()

    with mp.Pool(processes=2) as p:
        print(f"Time to init pool: {t(s):.2f}ms")

        f0 = p.apply_async(run0, args=(time.perf_counter(),))
        f1 = p.apply_async(run1, args=(time.perf_counter(),))

        r0 = f0.get()
        r1 = f1.get()
        print(r0, r1)

    print(f"Time to run end-to-end: {t(s):.2f}ms")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Below is the output that I typically get from running the above script

```
Time to init pool: 33.14ms
Time to reach run0: 198.50ms
Time to reach run1: 212.06ms
[[1. 1. 1. 1.]] [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
Time to run end-to-end: 287.68ms
```

Note: I'm looking to decrease the quantities on the 2nd and 3rd line by a factor of 10-20x smaller. I know that that is a lot, and if it is not possible, that is perfectly fine, but I was just wondering if anybody more knowledgable would know any methods. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if those are the real functions you are using, but if they are running them without `multiprocessing` is much faster, `Time to run end-to-end: 0.28ms`.

Comment: Processes take time to initialize and there's not much you can do here to reduce that time. Using multiprocessing to reduce the runtime of two 30ms functions is like building a car to visit your next door neighbor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

several points to consider:

- "Time to init pool" is wrong. The child processes haven't finished starting, only the main process has initiated their startup. Once the workers have actually started, the speed of "Time to reach run" should drop to not include process startup. If you have a long lived pool of workers, you only pay startup cost once.
- startup cost of the interpreter is often dominated by imports in this case you really only have `numpy`, and it is used by the target function, so you can't exactly get rid of it. Another that can be slow is the automatic import of `site`, but it makes other imports difficult to skip that one.
- you're on MacOS, and can switch to using "fork" instead of "spawn" which should be much faster, but fundamentally changes how multiprocessing works in a few ways (and is incompatible with certain OS libraries)

**example:**

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
# import numpy as np

def run():
    time.sleep(0.03)
    return "whatever"

def main():
    s = time.perf_counter()
    with mp.Pool(processes=1) as p:

        p.apply_async(run).get()
        print(f"first job time: {(time.perf_counter() -s)*1000:.2f}ms")
        #first job 166ms with numpy ; 85ms without ; 45ms on linux (wsl2 ubuntu 20.04) with fork
        s = time.perf_counter()
        
        p.apply_async(run).get()
        print(f"after startup job time: {(time.perf_counter() -s)*1000:.2f}ms")
        #second job about 30ms every time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks for the insight. Does using "fork" instead of "spawn" save time because the "fork" uses the resources already allocated in the calling thread? Also, this may be a deep question, but how does using "fork" instead of "spawn" change multithreading fundamentally? I'll give this the green check cause is shows  ways I can reduce the startup costs of using multithreading, but the overall idea that I'm getting from everyone is that it won't be beneficial enough due to the fast functions that I'm calling already.

Comment: Fork is a system call that copies the current process memory space and the new process is started without any real cpu overhead. nothing is re-imported, and nothing is re-processed. At the point the the call to `fork`, there are now two processes, and one takes one path, and the other takes a different (usually a "if" statement checking the pid which will be different in the child). Spawn is starts a new and separate process, and python must re-initialize. In order to have access to the same functions, the "main" script is imported, and all arguments are sent via a pipe to the new process.

Comment: https://www.wefearchange.org/2018/11/forkmacos.rst.html explains some of the details of fork on MacOS, and why it is not the default anymore. There are practical differences between fork and spawn which usually have people confused on global variables, and whether objects are the same or copies of each-other.

Comment: sorry for typos.... hopefully you could read my 3am mutterings

Comment: no dw about it. this was well explained and really helped my understanding, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can switch to python 3.11+ as it has a faster startup time (and faster everything), but as your application grows you will get even slower startup times compared to your toy example.

one option, is to run your application inside a linux docker image so you can use `fork` to avoid the `spawn` overhead, (though the COW overhead will still be visible)

the ultimate solution ? don't write your application in python (or any other language with a VM or a garbage collector), python multiprocessing isn't made for small fast tasks but for long running tasks, if you need that low startup time then write it in C or C++.

if you have to use python then you should reuse your workers to "absorb" this startup time in a much larger task time.